# How to target a specific shape in excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Program: Excel 2016.

I have a sheet with a lot of shapes. Each of them has its own specific name and most of them are label. I want to change their caption property, but i can't find a way but calling them one by one like this:

```
    LblLabel_1.Caption = ...
    LblLabel_2.Caption = ...
    LblLabel_3.Caption = ...
```

Instead i was looking for something like this:

```
    For BytCounter01 = 1 to 255
        Shapes("LblLabel_" & BytCounter01).Caption = ...
    Next
```

This one will result in error 438, basically saying Caption is not avaiable for this object. It still target the object, since this code:

```
    Debug.print Shapes("LblLabel_" & BytCounter01).Name
```

will return me its name.

Looking for a solution:

-i've tried Controls("LblLabel_" & BytCounter01) instead of Shapes("LblLabel_" & BytCounter01) but it won't work since Controls is only for userforms, not for sheets;

-i've tried Shapes("LblLabel_" & BytCounter01).TextFrame.Characters.Text but it returns error 438 again;

-since the label is a part of a group, i've tried both

```
    Shapes("ShpGroupOfShapes01").GroupItems(ShpShapeIndex).Caption
```

and

```
    Shapes("ShpGroupOfShapes01").GroupItems(ShpShapeIndex).TextFrame.Characters.Text
```

but got 438 again.

Is there really no way to easily target a specific label on a sheet and change his caption?

Thank you.

EDIT: thanks to Excelosaurus, the problem is solved. Since my labels are ActiveX Controls i have to use something like this:

```
    For BytCounter01 = 1 to 255
        Shapes("LblLabel_" & BytCounter01)OLEFormat.Object.Object.Capti‌​on = ...
    Next
```

You can check his response and comments for more details. Thanks again Excelosaurus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the textual content of a shape, use `.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text` as shown below:

```
shtShapes.Shapes(sShapeName).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = sShapeCaption
```

where `shtShapes` is the name of your worksheet's object as seen from the Visual Basic Editor in the Project Explorer,

[image: VBE showing worksheet codename]

`sShapeName` is a string variable containing the name of the target shape, and

`sShapeCaption`is a string variable containing the desired caption.

A code example follows. I've thrown in a function to check for a shape's existence on a worksheet, by name.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SetLabelCaptions()
    Dim bCounter As Byte
    Dim sShapeName As String
    Dim sShapeCaption As String

    For bCounter = 1 To 255
        sShapeName = "LblLabel_" & CStr(bCounter)

        If ShapeExists(shtMyShapes, sShapeName) Then
            sShapeCaption = "Hello World " & CStr(bCounter)
            shtMyShapes.Shapes(sShapeName).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = sShapeCaption
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Function ShapeExists(ByVal pshtHost As Excel.Worksheet, ByVal psShapeName As String) As Boolean
    Dim boolResult As Boolean
    Dim shpTest As Excel.Shape

    On Error Resume Next
    Set shpTest = pshtHost.Shapes(psShapeName)
    boolResult = (Not shpTest Is Nothing)
    Set shpTest = Nothing

    ShapeExists = boolResult
End Function
```

The result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tested the command in my file but it's giving me runtime error 5. I'll try to replicate your example in a whole new file so i can check it properly.

Comment: I've replicated the file, but the line shtMyShapes.Shapes(sShapeName).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = sShapeCaption is returning me runtime error «'-2147024809(80070057)': Specified value out of allowed values» (i've translated the description, so it might be not accurate). I can't see what i am doing wrong.

Comment: OK so your "labels" aren't regular shapes; they're either Form controls or ActiveX controls inserted from the Developer tab.
Form controls: `shtMyShapes.Shapes(sShapeName).OLEFormat.Object.Caption = sShapeCaption`

ActiveX controls: `shtMyShapes.Shapes(sShapeName).OLEFormat.Object.Object.Caption = sShapeCaption`

Comment: Ah! You got it, dude. It's an ActiveX control, so it works with the second one. Sorry that i didn't realize it could be important. I've tried a line so far, but i guess that it will work fine with all the code once i'll have updated it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a `Caption` to a Shape. *(Shapes don't have Captions)*.  One approach is to loop over the Shapes and build a little table to tell you what to loop over next:

```
Sub WhatDoIHave()
    Dim kolumn As String, s As Shape
    Dim i As Long, r As Range

    kolumn = "Z"
    i = 1

    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        Set r = Cells(i, kolumn)
        r.Value = i
        r.Offset(, 1).Value = s.Name
        r.Offset(, 2).Value = s.Type
        r.Offset(, 3).Value = s.TopLeftCell.Address(0, 0)
        i = i + 1
    Next s

End Sub
```

Which for my sample produced:

[image]

Seeing that I have both Forms and ActiveX *(OLE)* Controls, I know what to loop over next.  I then refer to the Control by number and assign a Caption if appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When you say you "know what to loop over next" and "refer to the control by number and assign a Caption if appropriate", do you mean that you can do it or the code can itself do it? How do you refer to the control by number and change his caption?